# Cmder changes Vim's colors under WSL

Tags: vim, terminal, console, cmder

I am using Vim under WSL (Ubuntu) and I installed Cmder for the support of unicode.
Also, I downloaded the [codedark](https://github.com/tomasiser/vim-code-dark/) colorscheme for Vim and under CMD it works perfectly:
[image]

But when I open it with Cmder, this is the result:
[image]

As you can see, the colors are not the same.

In Cmder, I chose Monokai as my colorscheme in the settings, and if I change it to something else, it changes the colorscheme of Vim too.

Why doesn't Vim override those settings when its on?
How can I make Vim use the same colorscheme under any console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't Vim override those settings when its on?

A console application (such as Vim) is not allowed to access OS graphics API directly. Instead, it talks to the terminal (Cmder), which, in turn, talks to OS.

Your screen has 24-bit colors (16 million), but Cmder provides for Vim only 8 bits (256 colors). Therefore, Vim can choose from only 256 *indexes* in Cmder's *palette*, i.e. a subset of some preselected colors (when you choose a colorscheme in terminal, you actually select colors in that palette). As those colors more or less differ from original codedark scheme, the resulting picture looks different too.

> How can I make Vim use the same colorscheme under any console?

Make sure your terminal offers a proper palette. Or switch both terminal and Vim to TrueColor mode. For Vim, it requires setting an option `termguicolors` on. For Cmder, I'm not really sure, but ConEmu, which Cmder is based on, does suppot TrueColor, so you can make a try.